# Position Alert dialog in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-jetpack-compose

How to position alert dialog in Jetpack Compose to the bottom of the screen. Also, set transparent background.

Comment: You can't. It's not designed for that. Create your own custom dialog and position it at the bottom.

Comment: thank @Johann, any reference for custom dialogs?

Comment: Just create one like you do any composable. Nothing special here.

Comment: @Johann, may i know how to position compose to bottom of the screen, regardless of layouts or size

Comment: Use a Box and place your content in the box and set the contentAlignment of the Box to bottomCenter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks, @alekseyHunter & @johann. I can able to achieve this with custom layout modifier.

Custom modifier to position alert dialog

```
enum class CustomDialogPosition {
    BOTTOM, TOP
}

fun Modifier.customDialogModifier(pos: CustomDialogPosition) = layout { measurable, constraints ->

    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints);
    layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight){
        when(pos) {
            CustomDialogPosition.BOTTOM -> {
                placeable.place(0, constraints.maxHeight - placeable.height, 10f)
            }
            CustomDialogPosition.TOP -> {
                placeable.place(0,0,10f)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in alert dialog implementation as

```
AlertDialog( ..., modifiers = Modifiers.customDialogModifier(CustomDialogPosition.BOTTOM)) 
{
    // block
})
```

Comment: I just want to implement an alert like a bottom sheet.

Comment: Cool, that's what I was looking for when implementing custom tooltip modal dialogs. If you have content just in Dialog and want to use this customDialogModifier, then just wrap dialog content to the box and add this modifier.

Comment: This essentially creates a full-screen dialog, and it breaks `dismissOnClickOutside` because there is no 'outside'.

Answer (score 16):

The solution that worked best for me, getting the idea from Vladimir's response, is to get a reference to the window from within the Dialog and set the desired gravity.

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = [...],
    properties = [...],
) {
    val dialogWindowProvider = LocalView.current.parent as DialogWindowProvider
    dialogWindowProvider.window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
    [...]
}
```

The cast shouldn't be an issue but, of course, it could be safe-casted to prevent unpleasant surprises.

Answer (score 1):

Look so simple.

```
Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Column() {
                /* Content */
            }
             /* Box alert */
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 32.dp, vertical = 16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Transparent, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .border(2.dp, Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Alert",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    color = Color.Black
                )
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @Rameshbabu changes the position of the dialog as expected. However, as was mentioned in the comments the dialog consequently becomes "fullscreen" and it can't be dismissed by tapping on the overlay.

I found another tricky solution. You can copy the source code of `androidx.compose.ui.window.AndroidDialog.kt` which comes with `"androidx.compose.ui"`. By doing this you'll be able to access the dialog's window directly and change its gravity and other parameters.

The simplest way would be to add some code in the `androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogWrapper` class. For example in the init function:

```
private class DialogWrapper(
    private var onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    ...
) : Dialog(ContextThemeWrapper(...){

...

init {
    val window = window ?: error("Dialog has no window")
    window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
    window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP) // This to be added
```

Hopefully, the Jetpack Compose team will make the compose Dialog more customizable in the future.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by copying the source code? Would this just entail cloning the git repo? and where and how would you add this to your own code