# How to display similar dialog to GMAIL and SYNC for reddit

Tags: android, dialog, android-jetpack-compose

I am struggling to understand how both Sync and Gmail have achieved this with there dialogs. I have tried different options such as [Position Alert dialog in Android Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390697/position-alert-dialog-in-android-compose), to move the alert dialog position however, I am still unable to get a similar appearance and lose the ability to tap outside to dismiss, which these two versions retain.

[image]

[image]

I am unsure how they can achieve the same result, both looking better than what I am able to achieve, while I am using a hacky solution. I am unsure if I'm missing something, maybe a different thing all together from Dialog/AlertDialog?

[image]

My current code implementation

```
if (openDialog) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
            menuStatus = !menuStatus
            openDialog = !openDialog
            expanded = !expanded
        },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        confirmButton = { null },
        text = {
            Column() {
                Row() {
                    Text(text = "Account Management")
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_logout_24),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(end = 8.dp)
                    )
                    Text(text = "Sign out", )
                }
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .customDialogModifier(CustomDialogPosition.TOP)
    )
}
```

```
enum class CustomDialogPosition {
    BOTTOM, TOP
}

fun Modifier.customDialogModifier(pos: CustomDialogPosition) = layout { measurable, constraints ->

    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints);
    layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
        when (pos) {
            CustomDialogPosition.BOTTOM -> {
                placeable.place(0, constraints.maxHeight - placeable.height, 10f)
            }
            CustomDialogPosition.TOP -> {
                placeable.place(0, 150, 10f)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `DialogFragment` and design the fragment layout however you want.
To get rounded corners, you could simply set the layout bg to a drawable shape with corners like [here](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/android-custom-fragmentdialog-with-round-corners-and-not-100-screen-width/)